# My localization using Google play Services doesn't work

Tags: android, google-play-services

In my app I need the localization services. I'm using Google Services because i found out that they are better and more precise than the Android. Location Manager. I watched different Tutos and tried different code but it is not Working neither in my Emulator nor in my Mobile phone.
Main2Activity:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private TextView textView;
private Button btn_localisation;
private Button btn_update_Localisation;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLocation;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;


private boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;


// Location updates intervals in sec
private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 sec
private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 sec
private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10; // 10 meters
private static final String TAG = Main2Activity.class.getSimpleName();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_localisation);
    textView.setText("Waiting for updates");
    btn_localisation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_localisation);
    btn_update_Localisation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_update_localisation);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

}

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended ( int i){
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Error: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude())+","+location.getLongitude());
    Toast.makeText(this, "Updated: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

}

Gradle.build:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'
```

Manifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="bayram.com.databasetutorial">

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ShowData" />
    <activity android:name=".Add" />




    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: in my LogCat, from my Log.i i got only the location failed as mentioned in the code, otherwise nothing else is mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works perfectly, the only thing to do is to give the application the permission to get to phone location.
TO do That Settings -> applications -> your app -> permissions and there activate the permission to the Location.

Answer (score 0):

replace this code :

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

}
```

with this :

```
@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {



    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);

            if (mLastLocation != null) {
                mLatitude =  mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                mLongitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
                Log.i(TAG, "Location"+mLatitude+"long"+mLongitude);

            }
            else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Location failed");

            }
        }
```

try without adding the checkSelfPermission(it will ask you for this avoid it), test and if it's run correctly add the checkSelfPermission test.

Comment: infortunally it doesn't work, i got this message:"I/Main2Activity: Location failed"